# I Can't receive files via bluetooth on lxde

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth, lxde

I needed to receive a PDF file from a friend in a class. I use ubuntu LXDE (13.10) and my friend had a Samsung tablet. I enabled bluetooth. We went through some sort of "setup" and entered a security code and so and it seemed that this step was completed successfully. He tried to send me the file but I had no notifications coming up or anything and he got a "sending error" after a while. I searched for a "receive mode" or something but couldn't manage to find anything. I was able to send a file to him!

Even later I looked around quickly in unity but still didn't know how to receive files.

...how? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late for an answer but just for the record :

- First : install the package **gnome-user-share** you can do this from the terminal with `sudo apt install gnome-user-share`
- Then : from the command line do

> gnome-file-share-properties

- There : Allow receive files in downloads folder over bluetooth

I don't know why we need to do this, it looks like unity does not expect to receive files over bluetooth ...

Comment: great! I think that's it! thanks :) it's great that I got the answer after all :)

Answer (score 1):

I use Lxde on Ubuntu 14.10 and I could not receive a file over bluetooth with `gnome-user-share`. I installed the blueman bluetooth manager, then:

- I could receive a file over bluetooth
- A bluetooth icon was added to my system tray

To install it, just run

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```