# Xubuntu 17.04 bluetooth unable to transfer files (transfer settings grayed out), gnome-user-share not an option

Tags: bluetooth, files, 17.04, transfer, blueman

Since upgrade to 17.04 I am unable to properly set-up receiving files via bluetooth, because in the "transfer settings" everything is grayed out.

[image: everything grayed out since 17.04]

It used to work just fine before. What can be done to make it work again? Thanks.

It might be a duplicate of [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381664/i-cant-receive-files-via-bluetooth-on-lxde) BUT, the problem is, by installing `gnome-user-share` I am forced to install 71 extra packages to my system including some Unity related packages like `libunity-control-center1`, `libunity-settings-daemon1` and other unrelated stuff. Have a look:

```
❱ sudo apt install gnome-user-share
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.8.0-58 linux-headers-4.8.0-58-generic linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-58-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apg cracklib-runtime dconf-cli evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-online-accounts
  geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-session-bin gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 ibus
  indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-power
  libaccounts-glib0 libcanberra-pulse libcheese-gtk25 libcontent-hub0 libcrack2
  libecal-1.2-19 libedata-cal-1.2-28 libertine-xmir-tools libertined libfcitx-config4
  libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libgeocode-glib0 libgeonames-common libgeonames0
  libgflags2v5 libgles2-mesa libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8
  libgoogle-glog0v5 libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common libibus-1.0-5 liblibertine1
  liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libsignon-glib1
  libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libubuntu-app-launch4
  libubuntu-download-manager-client1 libubuntu-download-manager-common1 libudm-common1
  libunity-control-center1 libunity-settings-daemon1 libunwind8 liburcu4 libzeitgeist-2.0-0
  mousetweaks nautilus-data python3-libertine ubuntu-app-launch ubuntu-system-service
  ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-control-center unity-control-center-faces unity-settings-daemon
  xmir zeitgeist-core
Suggested packages:
  evolution apache2-bin libapache2-mod-dnssd ibus-clutter ibus-doc ibus-qt4 click powerd
  unity-system-compositor content-hub fcitx nautilus python3-libertine-chroot
  python3-libertine-lxc python3-libertine-lxd gnome-screensaver | xscreensaver
  libcanberra-gtk-module gnome-screensaver zeitgeist-datahub
Recommended packages:
  systemd-services
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apg cracklib-runtime dconf-cli evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-online-accounts
  geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-session-bin gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-user-share gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0
  ibus indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-power
  libaccounts-glib0 libcanberra-pulse libcheese-gtk25 libcontent-hub0 libcrack2
  libecal-1.2-19 libedata-cal-1.2-28 libertine-xmir-tools libertined libfcitx-config4
  libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libgeocode-glib0 libgeonames-common libgeonames0
  libgflags2v5 libgles2-mesa libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8
  libgoogle-glog0v5 libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common libibus-1.0-5 liblibertine1
  liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libsignon-glib1
  libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libubuntu-app-launch4
  libubuntu-download-manager-client1 libubuntu-download-manager-common1 libudm-common1
  libunity-control-center1 libunity-settings-daemon1 libunwind8 liburcu4 libzeitgeist-2.0-0
  mousetweaks nautilus-data python3-libertine ubuntu-app-launch ubuntu-system-service
  ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-control-center unity-control-center-faces unity-settings-daemon
  xmir zeitgeist-core
0 upgraded, 71 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 22,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 50,7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Is there any more elegant and correct option how to transfer my files? Even just via command line, I do not want to have half of Unity on my XFCE just because of bluetooth :/

Comment: Is there a program named personal file sharing in the program menu?

Comment: nope, and it doesn't sound familiar to me at all

Comment: unfortunatelly, that does not help me, because:

1) ❱ sudo apt install gnome-f
gnome-flashback         gnome-flashback-common  gnome-font-viewer

(you see - no package by that name provided)

2) "blueman": ❱ sudo apt install blueman 
[sudo] password for crysman: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
blueman is already the newest version (2.0.4-1ubuntu2).

(already installed in newest)

any other ideas? thanks

Comment: Actually it is. I'm not sure what that hint is all about or where you are obtaining that. the link you state is not a duplicate clearly says to install gnome-user-share. I'll edit it to make it clear what to do.

Comment: OK, my fault, I am sorry. There is that package available, I had made a typo probably. The problem is that I do not want to install all 71 extra packages just to make bluetooth file sharing working again. Are there any other options?

Comment: I've edited my original post.

Comment: Most of these dependencies look like recommendations rather than hard dependencies. Could you please try `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends gnome-user-share` instead? That prevents the installations of all but the latter group. See [the accepted answer to “How to not install recommended and suggested packages?”](/a/179089/175814) for more. In the mean time I'm voting to keep this question closed.

Comment: Well, with this parameter I've achieved to successfully install the package without all the bloat (thanks for the hint), but, unfortunately, the option is still grayed out. I even rebooted to be sure it really has not helped :/ This is not a duplicate then, please re-open it again.

Comment: It is working now. I've done nothing, except for some regular updates. It seems some update has fixed the issue...